# exceljs node.js write file does not work on VPS but works on Localhost

Tags: node.js, excel

When I am trying to save excel file created with this repo: https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs#create-a-workbook
on a localhost it works, the file is got created and available to open and read and edit.
But when doing the same thing on my VPS the `.then` function and the `.catch` function just return nothing.
The file is actually created in the server but I got the next error when trying to open it:

```
The file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.
```

This is the code:

```
app.get("/excel/createDemoExcel", function(req, res, next) {

  var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
  workbook.creator = 'mydomain.com';
  workbook.lastModifiedBy = 'The name of the Team';
  workbook.created = new Date();
  workbook.modified = new Date();
  workbook.rightToLeft = true;

  let sheetParams = {
    views:[
      {
        xSplit: 1, ySplit:1
      }
    ],
    pageSetup: {
      paperSize: 9,
      orientation:'landscape'
    },
    views: [
      {
        rightToLeft: true
      }
    ]
  };
  workbook.addWorksheet('mySheet', sheetParams);

  let mySheet = workbook.getWorksheet('mySheet');

  mySheet.columns = [
    {
      width:20,
    },
    {
      width:20
    },
    {
      width:30
    }
  ];

  mySheet.addRow(["Raz", "Buchnik", "0509921014"]);
  mySheet.addRow(["Amos", "Fadlon", "0508555550"]);
  mySheet.addRow(["Dgani", "Lavi", "0501231231"]);

  mySheet.getRow(1).font = {
    size: 16,
    bold: true,
  };
  mySheet.getCell("A5").value = "Yes";
  mySheet.getCell("C5").value = "Yes1";
  mySheet.mergeCells("A5:C5");

  console.log("Trying to export");
  workbook.xlsx.writeFile("src/excelUploads/mySheet.xlsx")
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Exported");
    res.end("Excel");
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Errored");
  });

});
```

Maybe someone familier with?

Ive tried to set the directory 777 but still not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A bit annoying that they don't make this clear, but there is a separate module for some file types. According to the GitHub README.md, you can install this extension. They provide an installer script, so just:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guyonoche/exceljs-formats/master/install.sh -L | sudo bash
```

Hopefully this helps. I was really confused with this error myself.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to downgrade your version of Exceljs. See this topic: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/883

I also had the issue that it worked fine locally, but not on the server. Downgraded the package to 1.10.0 and everything works also on the server now.